# Aptana Studio 3.6.0 - Is The Javascript Debugger For Internet Explorer Deprecated?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, aptana3

I've been using Aptana Studio 3.4.2 since 2013 for HTML, CSS, and PHP development.  I'm now attempting to use it for JavaScript development.  I'm using Internet Explorer as my default browser development environment (it's my customer audience, not me, that requires IE!) on WampServer.

I've installed Aptana's Internet Explorer JavaScript debugger **using the on-screen instructions provided by Aptana 3.6.0.**  I am using the following JavaScript code to test whether or not the Internet Explorer debugger is working properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>HTML Page Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("Hello World<br><br>")
            document.write("Messed up)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I debug using the Aptana Internet Explorer debug configuration, the Aptana Studio JavaScript Debugger loads, then it is immediately closed by IE11 with an MSHTML.dll C0000005 error.  I dismiss the error, and the JavaScript code is loaded and executed in a new instance of the IE11 browser.  I can use the IE11 Developer Tools in this new browser instance to debug the JavaScript code.

I researched the files that Aptana installs when it enables its Internet Explorer JavaScript debugging functionality.  One of them is a "Microsoft Script Debugger" file named scd10en.exe.  The Microsoft Web page for downloading this file is titled "Script Debugger For Windows NT And Later."  When I read the "Details" section of this Web page it says that the file was published on 7/14/2005 and that its use has been deprecated!  Here's the link to the Web page:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22185

After learning this about the Microsoft Script Debugger I am now wondering if Aptana's entire Internet Explorer JavaScript debugging functionality is based on pre-IE11 technology that doesn't apply to IE11?  After spending two days trying to get Internet Explorer JavaScript debugging to work with IE11 in Aptana Studio 3.6.0 am I encountering outdated Aptana code that doesn't work with IE11?  Should I forget trying to debug in Aptana Studio and just use IE11's Developer Tools?

Thanks For Your Help -

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for the catch on the missing "<".  I've edited my code to correct it.